# Will linking a trilogy account to my CV make my CV discoverable from my account?

Tags: support, jobs, stack-exchange, linked-accounts

Since I use a handle that's not my real name on the trilogy, I'm a little concerned about what information is made available if I link an account (I obviously don't mind that potential employers can see anything)

If I link an account, is there any publicly accessible way to take my trilogy handle and access any CV information if the CV is not public but an account is associated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

The link is one way, from careers to SO. It is only visible on the careers side -- and even then *only* if you've either

- paid to file your CV and made it searchable by employers
  **or**
- set up a public CV URL and made your CV public

Answer (score 2):

If your CV is not public, then it is not publicly accessible, period.  It may be accessible through employer searches if you've filed your CV, though.